Discrepancy between bar chart and pie chart values in Grafana using Elasticsearch data
I'm new to working with data and am currently building a Grafana dashboard using data from Elasticsearch. I have a field called "Letters" that contains values like a, aa, ab, ac, b, ba, bb, bc, c, ca, cb, cc. In each cell, there can be one or more of these values.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I created a bar chart to count how often each value appears. The chart is based on the following settings:

Metric: Count
Grouped by terms of the "Letters" field.

I’ve also created 3 pie charts, each representing different groups based on the first letter of the values. For example, one group includes a, aa, ab, ac.
I used Lucene queries to filter the groups:

Letters:A
Letters:AA
And so on...
I've also used the same metric and grouping settings as above

The problem is that the values shown in the bar chart are much higher (and seemingly more accurate) than those in the pie charts.
I’ve tried improving the queries with wildcard searches, but it didn’t make a difference. I`ve also plaied around with other settings size and order by but could not achive the results that I wanted. Initially, I thought the query might only be counting when there's a single value in a cell, but that doesn’t seem to be the case either.
I was expecting the pie charts to show the same counts as the bar chart, just split into different subgroups, but they are much lower than expected. I'm now stuck and unsure how to resolve this.
Thanks so much for your time and ideas!
